# How are the equations of non linear data determined?

Tags: regression, curves, regression-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Did a lot of Google searching, but couldn't find a common-sense answer. For non linear equations like `y = a + b * x/2 + c * ln(x^2)`, I can see how substituting various values on the right hand side of the equation can yield a curve defined by the equation.

What I don't understand is how the equation was created. If I have some data points on a graph that appear to follow the pattern of an exponent, I could use a function like `y = e^x` to describe the data.

But if I have data points on a graph that appear like a more strange looking curve for which I don't know what equation might best describe it, how is it possible to create an equation that describes the curve? I'm puzzled at how somebody came up with the `x/2` and `ln(x^2)` (above equation) to describe some curve.

Comment: Usually there is some underlying basis for the model (physics, experience, etc.)

Comment: Unless you have a "physical" explanation for the mathematical model, this is pure empiricism. By the way, the equation that you wrote is unrealistic (possibly your random choice), because the constants 2 have little reason to be there.